# How to access remote mysql server on windows?

Tags: mysql, apache, appserver

I'm using appserv, I'm trying to access remote mysql server, in linux i can do it doing:

grant all privileges on *.* to 'user' identified by 'pass';

flush privileges;

and update the host to '%' and comment the line 'bind-address' on my.cnf, but in windows, i find my.ini but i can't find 'bind-address' there, i tried to put 'bind-address=0.0.0.0' but it doesn't work.

I can access my apache via ip, but i can't access the mysql.

I'm missing something?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried all steps outlined [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html)?